# how can i write a condition in ssis to verify if the column is a string doesn't contain numbers

Tags: ssis

i have an excel source to a data base but before i transmit the information in the column product-name  i have to verify if the information is a string without numbers in it(example:lion is correct but lion124 is wrong) , using conditional split
and after the verification i have to send a message in an excel file telling the user that the column that he wrote is not correct and if it is correct i will send it to the data base
how could i check for the column and how can i send a excel file ?

Answer (score 2):

I would run it through a script transformation and use c#.

Add a column (boolean) to your data and use this:

```
Row.NewColForIntTest = Row.YourStringColumn.Any(char.IsDigit);
```

Then conditionally split off the new column.

Comment: it  send me an error in Any(char.Isdigit)